# Contacts app disappeared

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-nexus, 4.3-jelly-bean, google-contacts

I've got a rooted Samsung Galaxy Nexus running Android 4.3 (Jelly Bean).
Since a week I can't find the contacts app. Seems like it disappeared.
It is NOT disabled (I've already checked).
I also tried to re-install it, using the .apk placed in /system/app, but the installer fails ("Application not installed").
Does anybody know how to fix, or should I better factory-reset my phone? I know this is a solution, but I'd prefer to fix it...

Thanks in advance

Giacomo

Answer (score 0):

The install fail is likely due to your system being read only. If you use es explorer, select tools and root explorer, and remount system to rw and try to install again. Also make sure your launcher (if it allows hiding icons) isn't hiding your contacts app

Comment: I installed es and activated root exploring. Then I remounted /system partition with rw permissions. Still same error...`mount|grep "system"` returns this `/dev/block/platform/omap/omap_hsmmc.0/by-name/system  /system ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0`

Comment: I forgot: I am using the default android launcher, so no way out to hide icons...anyway, I also can't see the contacts app from settings→app

Comment: Try adb shell su -c "mount -o remount rw, /system" then adb shell su -c "/sdcard/contacts.apk /system/app/"

Comment: You wrote `/sdcard/contacts.apk`. I have no external contacs.apk package. The only one I have is the one placed in `/system/app`. Should I download a new one?

Comment: Ah, okay. What you want to do is look for your roms contacts.apk online and copy it to your sdcard, then move it to system/app and reboot. It should reinstall the app

Comment: I downloaded a stock maguro image from source.android.com, then I copied the .apk and the .odex into /system/app and rebooted the phone. Still can't find contacts.apk, and when I try to execute the .apk, the installer fails to start ("Analysis error - failed to analyse the packet", or something like this - I use italian localization).

Comment: I did a factory reset (using ClockWorkmod...for some reason stock recovery isn't working :/). Now everything is OK. Really can't understand what happened. I really thank you for the help you gave me, hope this thread will help other users luckier than me! (unfortunately I can't vote you up - need more rep...)